# Couldn't connect to Oracle 11g using service name via toad but could connect using SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

I couldn't connect to Oracle 11g using Toad but I could connect using SQL Developer. I am receiving the following error message when connecting using Toad:

> ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in the
>   connect descriptor.

I have ticked the option "Service Name" instead of "SID" so I'm not actually expecting such error message since I'm not trying to connect using SID. However, I am able to connect using SQL Developer using "Service Name".

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing here? And why does it work for SQL Developer and not for Toad?

I'm using Toad 9.0.1.8 and Oracle SQL Developer 3.1.0.7 by the way.

Comment: Did you have record for this sid in tnsnames.ora? May be you are using 2 different instances of Oracle Client?

Comment: be sure of the variables, specially the SID name

Comment: @decho, Why do I even need to care about the SID when I'm using "Service Name"? And why does it work for SQL Developer without having to bother about SID?